# Javascript JSON.Stringify() what is undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I am using JSON.Stringify() in my javascript...

```
var jsonProp;
var json = { };
json.prop= { };
json.prop.Brand = $('.Brand' + val).val();
json.prop.Name = $('.Name' + val).val();
json.prop.Desc = $('.Desc' + val).val();
json.prop.Address = $('.Address' + val).val();
json.prop.Phone = $('.Phone' + val).val();
json.prop.Tag = $('.Tag' + val).val();
json.prop.City = $('.City' + val).val();
json.prop.Status = $('.Status' + val).val();
jsonProp = jsonProp + JSON.stringify(json);
```

and the result is :

```
"undefined{"prop":{"Brand":"","Name":"apotik AA","Desc":"","Address":"Address","Phone":"","Tag":"","City":"BEKASI","Status":"0"}}
{"prop":{"Brand":"","Name":"apotik AAaaaa. Bina Farma","Desc":"","Address":"Jl. RA. Kartini, Margahayu-Bekasi Tim., Kota Bks, Jawa Barat 17113","Phone":"","Tag":"","City":"BEKASI","Status":"0"}}"
```

why is "undefined" there? how can I set it? all I want to have is a JSONArray like this :

```
Prop{{"Brand":"value","Name":"value"},{"Brand":"value","Name":"value"}}
```

Please help

Comment: Why do you write `jsonProp = jsonProp + JSON.stringify(json);` at all instead of `jsonProp =  JSON.stringify(json);`?

Comment: @t.niese because it the content have a grid table and the val is the value of the index of that grid table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you declared `jsonProp` but didn't define it: `var jsonProp;`. When you don't set a value to a variable, it will be `undefined`.

Comment: i declared it as var jsonProp, but still undefined

Comment: @Richard It's still

Comment: Like I said, you just declared it but didn't define it. Set a value to it.

Comment: whoa, i undrestand now. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable without any unassigned value:

```
var jsonProp; // default value set to undefined by javascript.
```

Without any assignment. What javascript does is, it assigns a default value to `undefined`. That is how it works.  So, when you concatenate it:

```
jsonProp = jsonProp + JSON.stringify(json);
//         undefined + "{prop:{}}"
```

This happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `jsonBiz` wasn't defined yet.

So when you do

```
jsonBiz = jsonBiz + JSON.stringify(json)
```

You add an undefined value and a string. The first value is turned into the string "undefined", and the two are added.

Comment: sorry, i my bad, jsonProp/jsonBiz is var, in my script "var jsonProp;", i edited my question. thankyou

Comment: @Richard: yes, but that doesn't change the problem, just imagine my answer also says jsonProp wherever I wrote jsonBiz.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define jsonBiz before using it.

```
var jsonBiz = "";

jsonBiz = jsonBiz + JSON.stringify(json);
```

please try this.